Equivalence of norms in the trace space
I have the following question about trace spaces: Let $\Omega$ be a Lipschitz domain with Lipschitz boundary $\Gamma$. Consider the space of traces
$$
H^{1/2}(\Gamma) = \{g \in L^2(\Gamma) | \exists R_g \in H^1(\Omega): (R_g)_{|\Gamma} = g\}.
$$
Then, some books, e.g. Salsa, Sandro, and Gianmaria Verzini. 2022. Partial Differential Equations in Action: From Modelling to Theory,
define the norm in $H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$ by
$$
||g||_{H^{1/2}(\Gamma)} = \inf_{R: (R_g)_{|\Gamma} = g} ||R_g||_{H^1(\Omega)}.
$$
Other books, e.g. Grisvard, Pierre. 2011. Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains, define the norm on $H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$ by
$$
||g||_{H^{1/2}(\Gamma)}^2 = \int_\Gamma |g|^2 ds + \int\int_{\Gamma \times \Gamma} \frac{|g(x) - g(y)|^2}{|x - y|^2}ds(x) ds(y). 
$$
How are these two equivalent? Is there a way to explicitly compute the constants in the equivalence of norms for these two definitions?
